# Is retired out counted in the bowling average?

Tags: cricket, statistics, wicket

Is 'retired out' counted in the 'bowling average' of a bowler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As with run outs and the more obscure forms of dismissal (obstructing the field, etc), the bowler is not credited with a wicket for a batsman retiring.

While the effect of a batsman retiring is very similar to that of a wicket falling, it's actually a different procedure - in particular, a batsman who retired for any reason other than "illness, injury or any other unavoidable cause" (i.e. who would be recorded as "retired - out" if they do not resume their innings) can in fact resume their innings with the consent of the opposing captain - see [Law 2.9](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-2-substitutes-and-runners-batsman-or-fielder-leaving-the-field-batsman-retiring-or-batsman-commencing-innings/) for details (or the renumbered Law 25.4 in the October 2017 code).